# Convert Scala expression to Java 1.8

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to convert this Scala expression to Java:

```
val corpus: RDD[String] = sc.wholeTextFiles("docs/*.md").map(_._2)
```

This is what I have in Java:

```
RDD<String> corpus = sc.wholeTextFiles("docs/*.md").map(a -> a._2);
```

But I get an error on `a._2`:.

[image: Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to R]

If I go to the "super" method, this is what I see:

```
package org.apache.spark.api.java.function;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface Function<T1, R> extends Serializable {
        R call(T1 var1) throws Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala PairRDD is a Tuple type and you can access its members with `_1`and `_2`. However Java does not have built in Tuples so you have to use methods to get these members. It should look like this, since Java always requires parentheses on any function.

```
JavaRDD<String> corpus = sc.wholeTextFiles("docs/*.md").map(a -> a._2());
```

Edit: It seems that in Scala an implicit parameter is passed to the `map` method, which means you have to pass it explicitly in Java. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#map(scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) for the Java Doc and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) for the Scala documentation.

Edit 2: After a few hours of fumbling the answer was found, it had to be a JavaRDD.

Comment: I get the same error with this ... "String cannot be converted to R"

Comment: Now that's strange, `a`should be of type scala.Tuple2<String,String>. Can you check what type a is in your case?

Comment: This gets me the same error: (Tuple2<String, String> a) -> a._2(). But if I leave out the Strings: (Tuple2 a) -> a._2() - I get another error: cannot resolve method map(<lambda expression>)

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: Maybe this is a more relevant error: map(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<scala.Tuple2<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,java.lang.Object>)' in 'org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike' cannot be applied to '(<lambda expression>, scala.reflect.ClassTag<java.lang.Object>)'

Comment: Can you try to call it like this: `sc.wholeTextFiles("docs/*.md")
 .<String>map(a -> a._2())`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `values()` to get the result you want in Java here:

```
JavaRDD<String> corpus = sc.wholeTextFiles("docs/*.md").values();
```

Note that the type here is JavaRDD not RDD